# Based on Swagger, you can show or hide attributes on the same object depending on the endpoint

Tags: java, swagger

I have 2 endpoints. One endpoint save and the other endpoint do an update.  However I use the same object customerDTO on the body. Some attributes in this object is not necessary when I do an update and i don't wnat to  display in documentation (swagger-ui.html) only for endpoint where i do update. Can I do this using swagger our I need to create other DTO. One to save and other to update.

To create the documentation in swagger I am using annotations like @ApiModelProperty.

Comment: I would create new DTO for this. If its useful, you can make Save object inherit from Update object.

Comment: Hi Hitobat.Thanks for your help. So, this is the only solution? Create a new DTO?
Is it impossible do this using only swagger to show this in documentation?